# dlib dnn synchronisation seems to not store everything

Tags: c++, dlib

I noticed a strange behaviour with the trainer.set_synchronization_file().
As far as I undersood (according to trainer_abstract.h and implementation in trainer.h), it saves the current status of the trainer (inc net) so that we can stop the training at some point and restart from the exact same step.
However when using the example dnn_metric_learning_on_images_ex.cpp (from master b4a54490783). If I stop the training (e.g. ctrl+c) and then restart, the loss is decreasing significantly, as if some momentum was reset or so, and SGD is finding a better path for improvement.
As anybody an idea?
Here is some code sample. Only the stopping criteria is updated after synchronisation.

```
dnn_trainer<net_type> trainer(net, sgd(0.0001, 0.9), {1,0});
trainer.set_learning_rate(0.1);
trainer.be_verbose();
trainer.set_synchronization_file("face_metric_sync", std::chrono::minutes(5));
trainer.set_iterations_without_progress_threshold(10000);
// data loaders (...)
while(trainer.get_learning_rate() >= 1e-5)
{
    qimages.dequeue(images);
    qlabels.dequeue(labels);
    trainer.train_one_step(images, labels);
}
```

Here is an example of status before stopping:

```
Saved state to face_metric_sync
step#: 198726  learning rate: 0.001  average loss: 0.00928623   steps without apparent progress: 5923
step#: 198844  learning rate: 0.001  average loss: 0.00950317   steps without apparent progress: 6183
step#: 198963  learning rate: 0.001  average loss: 0.00971744   steps without apparent progress: 6525
step#: 199082  learning rate: 0.001  average loss: 0.00917967   steps without apparent progress: 6681
step#: 199200  learning rate: 0.001  average loss: 0.00942927   steps without apparent progress: 6834
step#: 199319  learning rate: 0.001  average loss: 0.00938926   steps without apparent progress: 6941
step#: 199438  learning rate: 0.001  average loss: 0.00917057   steps without apparent progress: 6915
Saved state to face_metric_sync
step#: 199552  learning rate: 0.001  average loss: 0.00964872   steps without apparent progress: 7487
^C
```

And after restarting

```
objs.size(): 75656
step#: 199507  learning rate: 0.001  average loss: 0.00974885   steps without apparent progress: 7146
step#: 199654  learning rate: 0.001  average loss: 0.00720691   steps without apparent progress: 64
step#: 199812  learning rate: 0.001  average loss: 0.00687095   steps without apparent progress: 209
step#: 199970  learning rate: 0.001  average loss: 0.00705782   steps without apparent progress: 439
step#: 200128  learning rate: 0.001  average loss: 0.00690515   steps without apparent progress: 584
```

Comment: Are you sure you aren't calling other functions that change training behavior *after* you call set_synchronization_file()?  Like maybe you are resetting the learning rate every time.

Comment: I added the relevant code for the calling order.

Comment: Looks fine. Maybe it didn't save anything yet. It only saves every 5 minutes.

Comment: The sync file looked ok because it restarted to a similar point. I added the status before stopping and after restarting. It happened at least twice AFAIR. Maybe I stopped right when it started to converge but twice in a row seems weird. I will test some more.

Comment: I could not reproduce this behaviour recently. At least not such a big gap in the loss.